# Draw on a bitmap with (0,0) being the center of the image

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to draw an arrow on a bitmap, but I want the (0,0) coordinate to be the center of the screen, so if I draw an arrow between (0,0) and (100,100) like this

```
Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
Point p2 = new Point(100,100);
graphics.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
```

I want the arrow to go from the center to the top-right corner, if the size of the bitmap is 200*200.

Is there any way to change this, so that (0,0) isn't in the top left corner?

Comment: You can use [Graphics.TranslateTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform?view=netframework-4.8). But you will need to __know the size__ of the total area! So `graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 100)`  should do the job in your case. Use (bmp.Width/2, bmp.Height/2) for the general case..! - Note that the __y-coordinates__ still will __start at the top__. If you want to reverse them use `Graphics.ScaleTransform(1,-1);`

Comment: @taw if a bmp/text or other "has a right way up" thing is drawn, will that scale tranform flip it upside down?

Comment: Yes, it will. To avoid that the graphics one could use a RotateFlipType but then the image will still be drawn upwards from a point. Better to revert the flip itself by doing a ScaleTransform(1,-1) before the DrawImage/DrawString. GDI graphics simply isn't math graphics and one has to know/decide where to make the compromises..

Comment: @kycklingsylt I do think it worth pointing out that TaW's technique doesn't move the 0,0 coordinate to the center of the canvas - it just makes it look that way by automatically sliding everything you draw across and down by 100 pixels and flipping it upside down. This will seem to work fine for simple shapes that dont have an orientation, but may have some unintended consequences for complex shapes, images and text. I'd genuinely recommend you get used to the "0,0 is topleft, drawing down/right" coordinate system rather than trying to adapt it to how you think about graphs from math lessons

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point, but in this specific case the source of my data uses a coordinate system where 0,0 is the center, so I need to make it work with that. Things ending up upside down is no problem since I'm just drawing lines between coordinates

Comment: As long as you don't use the `Graphics.ScaleTransform(1,-1);` nothing gets inverted, no matter what Caius thinks..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to change the drawing system so that 0,0 is not the top left corner. You can get the Graphics to apply a transformation (see @TaW's comments) but it has its drawbacks, such as rendering text and images upside down, or you can perform a mathematical conversion on the coordinates yourself:

```
Point ConvertAsIf00IsCenterAndPositiveYGoesUpwards(Point p, Rectangle r){

  return new Point(r.Width/2 + p.X, r.Height/2 - p.Y);

}
```

You want a line that goes from 0,0 to 100,100 in "your drawing system" (where 0,0 is the center and the range is -100 to +100 in both axes).

On a canvas area (the `Rectangle`) that is 200x200 using a "0,0 is top left" coordinate system, you actually want a line from 100,100 to 200,0..

This math converts your 0,0 point to 100,100 and your 100,100 point to 200,0. Similarly for other points like 100,-100 (your bottom right) it becomes 200,200 (drawing system's bottom right), and your -100,100 (your top left) becomes 0,0 (drawing system's top left) etc

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200,200);
Point p1 = new ConvertAsIf00IsCenterAndPositiveYGoesUpwards(Point(0,0), r);
Point p2 = new ConvertAsIf00IsCenterAndPositiveYGoesUpwards(Point(100,100), r);
graphics.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
```

You might want to name the method something more snappy.

To be honest, I'd say that developers probably find it easier and more effective to just get used to a coordinate system that has 0,0 as top left and positive values are down/right, even though this is a departure from the graph systems they got used to in elementary school maths where 0,0 is in the center and negatives move down/left, positives move up/right

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on how this answer could be improved?

Comment: I'll mark this as an accepted answer since it works, but for me the answer in the comments does the job and makes the code cleaner

Comment: I downvoted because the post start with a wrong statement. The transformation I suggested does move the origin to the center. It doesn't reverse the gdi y-axis, so it will keep the gdi orientation. There are many reasons fro having different orientations. Gdi goes the way all monitors go and also western text. Others, like geometry 101 or charts are different. OP never specified what he needs wrt y-orientation . If you add to the post I'll gladly revert my vote..

Comment: Check the math; because the new point is formed from half the canvas height minus the U value the user supplied it DOES reverse the Y orientation. If user supplies a y of +100 the math is 100-100=0 I.e. The top line of the canvas. If the user supplies -100 meaning bottom line, the math is 100 - -100 = 100 + 100 = 200 = bottom line of canvas.

Comment: The statement "there isn't a way to change the rule that 0,0 is top left and increasing Y is lower down" is true. Just because you can set a transform on the canvas doesn't alter the coordinate system of the canvas, it just moves everything you ask to draw, before it is drawn. It is essentially similar to what I propose, it's just that the coordinate transformation is performed by the canvas rather than by the user. It's like asking "I want foreach to iterate over the array in reverse, how can I do it?" The answer is "you can't change the direction of foreach but you can reverse the array" ...

Comment: ... foreach will always work forwards because it's the rule, but you applied a transform that means your array elements are processed in reverse order. This doesn't mean foreach works in reverse, just like applying a translate transform doesn't move the origin.. it just a manipulation of the data supplied to give the effect that the origin is moved/the foreach is reversed. If you see what I mean?

Comment: _there isn't a way to change the rule that 0,0 is top left.._ Graphics.TranslateTransform does just that. (And it doesn't reverse anything. It is basically like moving the canvas)  _..and increasing Y is lower down_ that is true by default.

Comment: Yeah, you're not getting me.. Don't worry about it